# Add array to key in web.config

Tags: c#, arrays, web-config

I was wondering if its possible to put an array as a value in a key...example

```
<add key="email" value="emails["email1@email.com, email2@email.com"] />
```

Would that syntax work?

Comment: If you are only needing a list of values you can just use a delimiter of your choosing (that is legal in XML, etc.) and split the value when you need to.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

With `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` you can only retrieve scalar values.  For your example, if you seperate your emails with a semicolon, you can do:

```
string[] emails = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["email"].Split(';');
```

with the web.config

```
<add key="email" value="email1@email.com;email2@email.com" />
```

Comment: brilliant answer :)