# How to Read Items into Arrays in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config

I'm trying to build an array of strings from items in a web.config file (in IIS).

**web.config**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="favourite" value="url1; site1" />
    <add key="favourite" value="url2; site2" />
    <add key="favourite" value="url3; site3" />
</appSettings>
```

**C#**

```
// Reads first favourite into string.
public string _favourites = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings ["favourite"];
```

I would like each **favourite** to be read into **string [ ] _favourites** array with the semi-colon (I would parse that out later). web.config is an XML file so I can open it as one and pull the data out, but is there an easier way to do this using ConfigurationManager?

Comment: Duplicate? - Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728491/add-array-to-key-in-web-config

Comment: `ConfigurationManager.Appsettings` will only return you the last value for the key. I found a workaround here, but I haven't tested it. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4302/How-to-make-AppSettings-work-with-multiple-values

Comment: No, that's not what I'm looking for.

<add key="email" value="email1@email.com;fullname1" />
<add key="email" value="email2@email.com;fullname2" />

Put all of that in string [] emails.

Comment: do duplicate keys make sense?

Answer (score 2):

What if you add all Array values in single key like -

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="favourite" value="url1;site1,url2;site2,url3;site3" />
</appSettings>
```

Read that key value as a string -

```
public string _favourites = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["favourite"];
```

and then split the string by ','(comma) like this -

```
string[ ] _favouritesArr = _favourites.Split(',');
```

This will give all values in array _favouritesArr.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a hack to do it, but I would just have one setting with multiple values;

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="favourite" value="url1;site1;url2;site2;url3;site3;" />
</appSettings>
```

or

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="favourite" value="url1=site1;url2=site2;url3=site3;" />
</appSettings>
```

Another solution is a separate configuration file or store this in a database.

I imagine that the favourites would change and changing `web.config` has consequences - it may cause your app to restart.

Answer (score 0):

How about:
1.right click on project > properties
2.Navigate to settings. If it shows, This project does not have settings file. click to create one.
3.Create a SystemCollections.Speciliazed.StringCollection
4.Name it, as you want (my example StatusReason). and in end of line on e right there is ...(three) dots
5.Press them and add as much settings needed. One per line.
Sample:

```
Valid=979580000
Invalid=979580001
Broken=979580002
ReadyForCollect=979580003
Missing=979580004
Refine=979580005
```

and in web config it looks like that.

```
<applicationSettings>
<WebApplication.BookServices>
     <setting name="StatusReason" serializeAs="Xml">
            <value>
              <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                              <string>Valid=979580000</string>
                <string>Invalid=979580001</string>
                <string>Broken=979580002</string>
                <string>ReadyForCollect=979580003</string>
                <string>Missing=979580004</string>
                <string>Refine=979580005</string>
              </ArrayOfString>
            </value>
          </setting>
</WebApplication.BookServices>
</applicationSettings>
```

and get your array of strings :

```
var settings = Settings.Default.StatusReason;
//TODO add any logic, if needed to split
```

add your project reference to properties:

```
using WebApplication.BookServices.Properties;
```

and there you have a array of settings.

Comment: Add your delimiter ';'  Sorry, I did not suited my example for your direct needs. My delimiter was '='  and adding them to dictionary `var settings = Settings.Default.StatusReason;
            Dictionary<string, string> statusReason= new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var set in settings)
            {
                string[] words = set.Split('=');
                statusReason.Add(words[1],words[0]);
            } `